# Make A4 pages pdf report

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, pdf, printing

I have an [html page](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QbWNH6N0m7UBdNwrfiU9gefQfcHmygtS/view?usp=sharing).
When the user presses the `Δημιουργία pdf` button, with javascript I cut the HTML code of `#page` into separate A4 pages.
The result is really good. It cuts a list of divs correctly, and it also cut one table with fixed rows correctly into separate pages.

Now, the question is: How can I make the PDF?
I am looking for a simple solution like: `window.print();` or `$("all_pages").print();`

Thanks in advance,

Chris Pappas

Comment: Have you tried [jsPDF](https://github.com/mrrio/jspdf)?

Comment: Yes. I think i will implement it with a server side solution.